# Custom gantt view showing documents and applicable project phase

Tags: 2013, gantt-view

I am trying to create a **custom gantt view** to show a list of project documents and which project phases they span across (similar to the below image).

Instead of inputting start and end dates I would like to enter a project phase as the beginning and similarly another project phase as the end date.

I have added a checkbox column to documents so that each document can be given a phase range attribute but I do not know how to bring this data through to the gantt view.

After a bunch of searches, I can't seem to find anything on how this could be done.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up getting this to work, but without the use of the **gantt view**.

I created a series of calculated columns for each project phase that load an image based on the Boolean input of a series of corresponding Yes/No columns.

The calculated column must have the **data type** set to **number** as this interprets HTML rather than just displaying the text. The calculated column formula displays one of two images (a blank or coloured rectangle) through the use of a simple **IF** statement based on the Boolean input.

Formula:

```
=IF([PhaseInputColumn]=TRUE,"<img src=' .../Website%20Images/Phase.png'>","<img src='.../Website%20Images/Blank.png'>")
```

The result is not what I originally had in mind but it does work well:

[image]

Comment: Great job my bro , and I have some question ? Should you tell me  what PhaseInputColumn refer to ? are you select phase during adding the data at new form and how you do that per project ? is it also selected also in a new form?

Comment: Thanks. It is all set up through the document library settings. A **column** is added for each project phase (Phase A Input, Phase B Input ... ) with a **Yes/No checkbox**. Corresponding **calculated columns** are added for each project phase (Phase A, Phase B ...) and they will host the formula mentioned in the answer. The **PhaseInputColumn** is a reference to the **Yes/No checkbox column** i.e. in this case the first one would be **Phase A Input** . By editing each document you will then have the option to place a tick next to each project phase. Hope that helps...